# Get Cloudformation script from SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I  have several SAM files but I want to convert those to cloudformation files so I can use StackSets (stackset does not support transforms).

Is there a way to do this?

My idea is to create a pipeline step to convert and deploy in stackset so I can do executions in several AWS Accounts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to convert packaged SAM Template to a vanilla Cloudformation template.

You can achieve this with the following easy steps:

```
pip install aws-sam-translator docopt

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awslabs/serverless-application- model/develop/bin/sam-translate.py`

python sam-translate.py --template-file=input_file.yml --output-template=output_file.json
```

Now you have a packaged vanilla CloudFormation template at output_file.json

You can associate this template to your stackset.

More on this at https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/develop/bin/sam-translate.py